# How to work with Amazon report files ('asin' identifiers...)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

The CSV files looks like this

```
Stock

asin          name         quantiy
----------------------------------
B01EI65LTI    Blue Shoes   20
B079VGHTM2    Black Shoes  10
B07B33J5CK    Green Shoes  3

Storage fees

asin        currency   estimated-monthly-storage-fee
----------------------------------------------------
B01EI65LTI  EUR        0.7988
B079VGHTM2  GBP        0.4656
B07B33J5CK  EUR        0.1264

Sales

amazon-order-id        asin        quantity    item-price
----------------------------------------------------------
404-2135868-6928346    B01EI65LTI  1           59.95
402-0310960-9618709    B079VGHTM2  1           18.95
403-6094647-7799558    B07B33J5CK  1           14.95
```

Currently my solution is adding extra ids and associations to the
entities, for example, Stock and Storage fees

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\StockRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(indexes={@ORM\Index(name="asin_idx", columns={"asin"})})
 */
class Stock
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=16) */
    private $asin;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) */
    private $productName;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $afnWarehouseQuantity;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="StorageFee")
     * @JoinColumn(name="storageFeeId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $storageFee;    
}

/** @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\StorageFeeRepository") */
class StorageFee
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=16) */
    private $asin;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=8) */
    private $currency;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="float") */
    private $estimatedMonthlyStorageFee;
}
```

and "bulk insert" the entitys

```
class StockRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository 
{
    public function insertFromFile(string $fileName)
    { 
        $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()
             ->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);

        // read csv...
        foreach ($csv as $row) {

            $stock = (new Stock())
                ->setAsin($row['asin'])
                ->setName($row['name'])
                ->setQuantity($row['quantity'])
            ;

            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($stock);

            if (($numInsert % $20) === 0) {
                $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
                $this->getEntityManager()->clear();
            }
        }

        $this->getEntityManager()->flush(); // flush remaining
        $this->getEntityManager()->clear();
    }
}
```

and "bulk update" the association in a secound step.

```
public function updateAssociation()
{
    $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()
         ->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT sf.id, sf.asin FROM App\Entity\StorageFee sf');
    $storageFees = $query->getResult();

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('UPDATE App\Entity\Stock s SET s.storageFee = :id WHERE s.asin = :asin');

    foreach ($storageFees as $row) {
        $query->setParameter('id', $row['id'])
              ->setParameter('asin', $row['asin']);
        $query->execute();
    }
}
```

I tried my best, but with these large files (up to 35.000 rows) 
I have still very long script runtimes - 20-40 secounds. And to set 
associations in a secound step looks not very 'professional'.
I think. But mixing insert and updates with +60 secound runtimes (?)
is also a problem.

Maybee I have the wrong concept. It is recommended to use here the
existing asin as the key? Never worked with string keys before ...
and haven't done very much with doctrine yet.

I would be very happy, about any suggestion.
Thank you & Best regards

Comment: I think, inserting 35,000 rows is always going to be somewhat slow. I would worry about that, when it becomes a problem. When it does, consider going back to bare sql, prepared statements and keeping a map [asin -> id], if you want to use your own id. (have a look at how to get a "reference" object, if you want to hold on to the entity manager: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L374-413). also, I hope you don't flush every 20 rows ... could be higher ;o)

Comment: @Jakumi thank you very much. working with maps and higher batches really helps. I have posted an example below

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Jakumi - I have updated my code and it is twice as fast with one step in the right import order.
(batch sizes of 200 results in higher peak memory usage)

```
class StockRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository 
{
    public function insertFromFile(string $fileName)
    { 
        $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()
             ->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null);

        // get storeage fee ids
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(/** @lang DQL */'
                SELECT sf.id, sf.asin 
                 FROM App\Entity\StorageFee sf
        ');

        $map = [];
        foreach($query->getResult() as $row) {
            $map[$row['asin']] = $row['id'];
        }


        // read csv...
        foreach ($csv as $row) {

            $stock = (new Stock())
                ->setAsin($row['asin'])
                ->setName($row['name'])
                ->setQuantity($row['quantity'])
            ;

            // add reference
            if (isset($map[$row['asin']])) {
                $storageFee = $this->getEntityManager()->getReference('App\Entity\StorageFee', $map[$row['asin']]);
                $stock->setStorageFee($storageFee);
            }

            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($stock);

            if (($numInsert % 200) === 0) {
                $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
                $this->getEntityManager()->clear();
            }
        }

        $this->getEntityManager()->flush(); // flush remaining
        $this->getEntityManager()->clear();
    }
}
```